# Color code php inside of css in Dreamweaver

Tags: php, css, colors, dreamweaver

I'm creating a dynamic css stylesheet with php variables in it. I would like to have any code that appears inside the  tags color coded as if it was a php file, while everything outside is css color coded.

As it is now, everything is color coded for css and the file is .css (I'd like to keep the .css file extension).

I'm using Dreamweaver CS3 on Windows 7.

Thanks

Comment: This question is about a program, so is a better fit for superuser. Voted to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to edit this behavior in Dreamweaver.  Dreamweaver does its best to detect what language things are in and color code accordingly, but what you are describing is a fundamental change in the way the code editor interprets code.

You will need to use different editor.